# How to deregister automatic unhealthy instances from a AWS target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-auto-scaling

I created an ElasticBeanstalk with an Application Load Balancer. A target group and an auto scaling group were created. So far so good. However, if an instance becomes unhealthy, it will not be deleted from the target group. What are the necessary configurations so that the unhealthy instances are automatically terminated? In the Beanstalk Events it is shown as "Severe".

Comment: What do you meany by automated termination? You want to reduce deregisration delay?

Comment: If health checks detect an unhealthy instance, the instance will be terminated by the Auto Scaling group. Did you have an unhealthy instance that was _not_ terminated?

Comment: Correct @JohnRotenstein I have used the sample PHP application and connect to the instance. After that I removed the index.php so the instance reached the unhealthy state but was not terminated by the Auto Scaling group. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did the Load Balancer recognize the instance as being Unhealthy? If not, look at the Health Check settings for the Load Balancer. Then, if the Load Balancer saw it as Unhealthy, but it was not terminated by Auto Scaling, ensure that the Auto Scaling group health check type to **ELB**.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein, you are right, the Elastic Beanstalk Generator from AWS is missing to activate the check box under EC2 -> Auto Scaling Groups -> Health checks -> Health check type -> ELB. This will remove instances when they are unhealthy.